# How to install php 5.3 on Ubuntu 14.4 with plesk 12? Missing libxml2

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.3, ubuntu-14.04

I need php 5.3 in reason of compatibility. I tried to install it under Ubuntu 14.4 with:

```
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf php-5.3.28.tar.bz
cd php-5.3.28
./configure --prefix /usr/local/php53
```

However it returns the error:

```
checking libxml2 install dir... no
checking for xml2-config path... 
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

libxml2 and xml2 are installed and uptodate

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Typo tar -xvjf php-5.3.28.tar.bz must be tar -xvjf php-5.3.28.tar.bz2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the developer support for libxml2, otherwise you can only *use* software that is already built against it, you can't compile that software yourself.

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: typo: alt-get install libxml2-dev must be apt-get install libxml2-dev